# Magento 2 : Difference between is_used_for_price_rules and is_used_for_promo_rules?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

Catalog product attributes have two properties (can be found in **catalog_eav_attribute** table)

- is_used_for_price_rules
- is_used_for_promo_rules

I suspect that they connect to cart and catalog rules.

What does each of the properties refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `is_used_for_promo_rules` is used for conditions in both rules: cart and catalog rules. I.e. if the property for an attribute is set to 'yes' you can use that attribute for conditions in cart and catalog rules.

I guess the property `is_used_for_price_rules` isn't used anymore and it's functionality has been removed in some 1.x version: In version 1.6 it still was used (https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php) but in version 1.9  as well as in Magento 2 I don't see any usage of this property.

I have no clue why the property has been included in the Magento 2 schema.